# How to use jQuery to show a different page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am trying to set up functionality similar to Netflix. Where if you mouseover a movie - you are presented with a window of movie details (all client-side).

At high level, can someone in this forum help by telling me how this should be implemented?  I.E., one or more .aspx pages, what would go in code-behind, and .js file, css, etc.  Just trying to get an idea on how this would be set up to work.

Basically, when I hover over an item, I need to query for details that belongs for that record being moused-over and display it in the window or div.  I also need to have some functionality in that window (i.e. a textbox and button which will end up needing to get saved in a database).

Thanks for any tips and suggestions -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to add an `AJAX` call to the `hover` event of the image, that pulls from a webservice/web method.

Here is a good example, you would change some things. However, it should get you started.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery

Comment: Do you happen to know of any examples available online?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you should try this excelent jQuery plugin:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/css-on-hover-image-captions/

Look at the demo here:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/image-hover/

easy to install and configure and very slick!

Good luck

EDIT: sorry wrong lik the first time

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly many [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/) that will do this for you.  [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) may also be of benefit.

Here is one that appears to do something like you are describing:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/VisualLightbox